# Removing empty parameters in url by php

Tags: php, url

I echo URLs using the code below:

```
echo '<a class="list-group-item" href="'._siteurl.'/search.php?Location='.$Location.'&Select='.$Select.'&countrySelect='.$countrySelect.'&type='.$type.'" title="'.$type.' '.$Select.' | '.$Location.' '.$countrySelect.'">'.$type.'</a>';
```

Sometimes parameters/parameter have empty values and I want remove those parameters.

I tried if else function but it requires to include all possibilities, is there a better way to remove empty parameters?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assemble an array of your parameters before starting any output, that way you can filter out empty values etc:

```
$Location = 'Somewhere';
//$Select = 'John';
$countrySelect = 'USA';

$params = array(
    'Location' => $Location,
    'Select' => $Select,
    'countrySelect' => $countrySelect,
    'type' => $type
);

echo '<a class="list-group-item" href="/search.php?' . http_build_query($params) . '" title="'.$type.' '.$Select.' | '.$Location.' '.$countrySelect.'">'.$type.'</a>';
```

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) [will not use any array entries that don't have values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#60523) (filtering for you!).

[Example](https://eval.in/550775)

Please keep in mind that you will get undefined variable warnings if you write your code this way. It's better to conditionally check before *adding* a value to the array, rather than add everything regardless of whether it exists or not, then filter out the ones that don't exist.

**Edit:** if `http_build_query()` doesn't strip out empty values for you for some reason, use `array_filter()` as well:

```
$params = array(
    // ...
);

$params = array_filter($params);
```

Comment: Used your code, no errors but still shows empty parameters, PHP version could be a problem?

Comment: @Smith perhaps - if the empty parameters are still present then try adding `array_filter()`, i.e. `$params = array_filter($params);` before building the querystring

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Robbie Averill up there, here's a code that will allow you to do exactly as you want. In this example you'll see the Name parameter being empty and therefor removed from the URL:

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/search.php?Location=test&Name=&Age=12';

// Get host
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

// Get parameters
$params = parse_url($url);
parse_str($params['query'], $query);

// Remove empty
$cleanedParams = array_filter($query);

// Count array
$count = count($cleanedParams);

// Build new URL
$newURL = 'http://'. $host .'/search.php?';

$i = 0;

foreach ($cleanedParams as $key => $cleanParam){
    $newURL .= $key . "=" . $cleanParam;

    if($i < $count - 1){
        $newURL .= "&amp;";
    }

    $i++;
}

echo $newURL;
```

In this case I guess it wasn't nessesary to get the host out of the URL. I simply did this to show that it's possible to get any information you want out of an URL and do something with it using [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url).